# play live socket stream's PCM raw data using Flash

Tags: flash, sockets, pcm, actionscript-3

I've been searching a lot about the ability of flash to play RAW PCM audio data, since I have RAW PCM audio as ByteArray, I'm just thinking if flash can actually play it, some article says yes, some no, please note that the RAW PCM audio is coming from a live socket stream

As of now what I've tried was to make an empty Sound object, and then call its play method and then handle its SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA event and pass the bytes from there, some code snippets below:

```
sound = new Sound();
sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, sampleDataHandler);
.... 
pa.readBytes(soundBA, soundBA.length); 
if (soundBA.bytesAvailable >= (8192 * 4))
{
    sound.play(); 
}
....
private function sampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void {

    var i:int;
    for (i = 0; i < 8192 && soundBA.bytesAvailable > 0; i++) 
    { 
        var sample:Number = soundBA.readFloat(); 
        event.data.writeFloat(sample); 
        event.data.writeFloat(sample); 
    }
}
```

So by doing this I'm able hear static sound (pretty much all NOISE) at certain intervals since as you can see I have this check `soundBA.bytesAvailable >= (8192 * 4)` and so the play method will only be triggered once I have enough data.

So my question is now, does this sound (the noise I hear) means that Flash is able to play the PCM audio? OR it just means that it is unable to play it and so only noise can be heard?

===== EDIT ======

**I just discovered that the audio I'm processing has 16bit per sample and so I adjusted the code a bit by doing `soundBA.bytesAvailable >= (8192 * 2 * channels)`, and also I made sure to pass a value of range -1 to +1 to my `event.data.writeFloat(sample)` call but still the sound is still scratchy**

**Is there any way to set the sampling rate (Hz) of the Flash sound object? or is it always thinking that you're using 44100Hz?**

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that 44kHz is the default. However, you can change this in Flash Professional (I have CS5).

In your Library, right click on the sound file you want to change the sampling rate of. On the Options tab, change "Compression" from "Default" to another format (mp3 does not have a sampling rate option, but the others do.) You can change the sampling rate here. Click "OK" to save.

As for an in-code method, I do not know if there is even a way. If someone else knows how to do that in code, please post it.